# Custom Contains like method implementation for LINQ to SQL to generate query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using EF6 for data model and i'm bound to use LINQ to SQL with generic repository, we're generating some queries to filter data and use Contains for performing filter and it is generating query with CHARINDEX, now i want's to implement same Contains function with including specific Collate,

```
   var contactFilterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<CON_CONTACT>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactRequest.Email))
        {
            contactFilterPredicate = contactFilterPredicate.And(x => x.CON_EMAIL.Contains(contactRequest.Email));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactRequest.Name))
        {
            contactFilterPredicate = contactFilterPredicate.And(x => x.CON_FIRST_NAME.Contains(contactRequest.Name) || x.CON_SURNAME.Contains(contactRequest.Name));
        }
        return contactFilterPredicate;
```

which has a SQL output is

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1] FROM (SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[CON_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[CON_FIRST_NAME] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~')
OR ([Extent1].[CON_SURNAME] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')) AS [GroupBy1]
```

and i want's to use MyContains to generation it with Collate

```
   var contactFilterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<CON_CONTACT>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactRequest.Email))
        {
            contactFilterPredicate = contactFilterPredicate.And(x => x.CON_EMAIL.MyContains(contactRequest.Email));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactRequest.Name))
        {
            contactFilterPredicate = contactFilterPredicate.And(x => x.CON_FIRST_NAME.MyContains(contactRequest.Name) || x.CON_SURNAME.MyContains(contactRequest.Name));
        }
        return contactFilterPredicate;
```

and i expect to generate like

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1] FROM (SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[CON_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[CON_FIRST_NAME] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~')
OR ([Extent1].[CON_SURNAME] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')) AS [GroupBy1]
```

So is it possible to create ? if yes then how ?

Comment: The question is not clear to me, what do you want MyContains method to do?

Comment: It should append or add COLLATE also for comparison. like, [Name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI LIKE @linq__p1, is it's clear enough ?

Comment: @AdilMammadov : Look at the updated question, in which i had added sql query which is generated and which i'm targeting to generate. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: yes, it is pretty clear now. The problem is that I see *Collate* first time (may be because I work with Oracle), so I didn't understand it.

Comment: @AdilMammadov : Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have eniugh knowledge on this. As far as I know, EF translates queries internally, so if they have not provided a method for it, you cannot do this. But I am telling again, I do not have enogh knowledge on this.

Comment: @AdilMammadov : Never mind, thanks.